# Swift: Setting the Value of a Nested Dictionary?

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

Say I have array of dictionaries like so:

```
var dict = [
             [
        "subcategories": [
                            [ "name": "ATV", "type": "boolean", "value": "0"],
                            [ "name": "Bike Paths", "type": "boolean", "value": "0"]
                        ]
         ]
    ]
```

In playground, I can set the values of the dictionary like this:

```
dict[0]["subcategories"]![1]["name"] = "abc"
```

But in Xcode 5 Beta 5, I get the compiler error `(String, AnyObject) does not have a member name 'subscript'`. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, Beta 7 is now available. Just as a passing comment I'd recommend updating.

Comment: I've tested that code in beta 7 (in a "regular" project), and it compiles

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like type inference is failing you for some reason -- try explicitly declaring the type:

```
var dict: Array<Dictionary<String, Array<Dictionary<String, String>>>> = [
    [
        "subcategories": [
            [ "name": "ATV", "type": "boolean", "value": "0"],
            [ "name": "Bike Paths", "type": "boolean", "value": "0"]
        ]
    ]
]
```